# Understanding IO monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I'm trying to understand asynchronous computation by `cats.effect.IO` examples and got some misunderstanding. The `unsafe` method `unsafeRunAsync` seems like running the underlying effect asynchronously (I expected that some `ContextShift` to be provided). But the method looks simply like this:

```
final def unsafeRunAsync(cb: Either[Throwable, A] => Unit): Unit =
  IORunLoop.start(this, cb)
```

Neither `ContextShift` nor `ExecutionContext` is provided. Here is the very simple example:

```
object TestIo extends App {
  println(s"Main thread = ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
  val io = IO {
    println(s"Effect thread = ${Thread.currentThread().getName}")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
  io.unsafeRunAsync(_ => println(s"Callback thread = ${Thread.currentThread().getName}"))
  println(s"Finished")
}
```

The output is

```
Main thread = main
Effect thread = main
Callback thread = main
Finished
```

As you can see everything here is run in the ***main thread*** ***synchronously***. Can you please explain `unsafeRunAsync`? To me it seems the same as `unsafeRunSync`.

Comment: @erip Unrelated tag deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About

> Neither ContextShift nor ExecutionContext is provided.

There is a context switch in `cats.effect.IO`

See this blog: https://www.jaspervanzandbeek.com/scala/cats-io-monad/

Here an example from there:

```
def blockingOperation(): String = {
  // Read from file
  ...
}

val result: IO[String] = for {
  _ <- IO.shift(executionContextForBlockingOperations)
  result <- IO { blockingOperation() }
  _ <- IO.shift(mainExecutionContext)
} yield result
```

Comment: `IO.shift` requires either `ContextShift` or `ExecutionContext`. `unsafeRunAsync` does not.

Comment: Ah... I just tried it myself and saw the difference. A subtle thing...  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `unsafeRunSync` and `unsafeRunAsync` is whether or not the thread is blocked. You're forcing your thread to block by using `Thread.sleep` in the body of your `IO` monad. By doing this, you're forcing it to behave synchronously.

Because `IO` is a monad, it will still do its computation sequentially, though. Therefore, your prints will always be in that order.

Comment: Exactly. As I just understood we can shift out the blocking operation and get the asynchronous behavior. Thanks.